CORS Error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check (Shopify App)
I'm developing a Shopify app and facing a CORS error when trying to send a request from the storefront to my server.
Error:
Access to fetch at 'https://multimedia-arg-such-transcript.trycloudflare.com/api/assistant?query=Hello' from origin 'https://getvoicecart.myshopify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
Storefront Request Code:
fetch(`https://multimedia-arg-such-transcript.trycloudflare.com/api/assistant?query=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: "include",
})

CORS Headers in api.assistant Response:
return json(
  { response: processedResponse },
  {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": `threadID=${threadID}; Path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=86400;`,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://getvoicecart.myshopify.com/",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, _shopify_y",
    },
  }
);


Question:
Why am I still facing this CORS error, and how can I fix it? Is there something specific to Shopify or Cloudflare that could cause this issue?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Steps I’ve Tried:

Ensured that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is set to my Shopify domain (https://getvoicecart.myshopify.com).
Added "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true" to allow cookies and credentials.
Checked the request URL, method, and credentials in the fetch call.
Confirmed that the Cloudflare server is reachable.


I believe there should be no trailing slash at the end of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header value

@blex Thank you for your suggestion! I removed the trailing slash from the Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Unfortunately, the issue persists. I'm still getting the same error :(
Do you have any other suggestions or ideas on what might be causing this? Could it be related to something in Shopify's proxy settings or another misconfiguration on my end?

does the server configuration you've shown add CORS headers to pre-flight requests?

Crafting CORS response headers and handling pre-flight OPTIONS requests is something best left to mature, well tested libraries / modules. Surely whatever you're using for your server has such an option

It looks like you have something in place to handle pre-flight OPTIONS requests but it is configured incorrectly. Figure out where that configuration comes from and fix it

@Bravo Yes, the server configuration provided is intended to add CORS headers to pre-flight requests. Specifically, it sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in response to OPTIONS requests. If these headers are not being reflected in responses, it might indicate that the middleware handling pre-flight requests is not being executed correctly or is being overridden by another configuration (e.g., a proxy like Cloudflare)
Thank you!

@Phil Thank you for pointing that out. The pre-flight OPTIONS requests are handled by a middleware on my server, where I explicitly set the CORS headers
However, based on the feedback and behavior I'm observing, it seems that these headers might be overridden or not applied correctly. One potential source of the issue could be Cloudflare, which I am using as a tunnel. I'll investigate if it’s modifying the headers or if there’s a misconfiguration in the middleware itself. Thank you!
